# Exclude specific spans from string when substituting by regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this problem.
Assume there is a pretty long and complicated text file where you can meet such special blocks in delimiters (which can be empty):

```
some text
----
text inside special block
----
some text
----
----
some text
----
text inside special block
----
```

The task is to make some substitutions in the whole text but exclude text inside these borders (`----`) from these substitutions.

So for example we need to replace all `text` substrings with `TEXT` strings but not inside special blocks. The result should be:

```
some TEXT
----
text inside special block
----
some TEXT
----
----
some TEXT
----
text inside special block
----
```

We cannot use lookahead or lookbehind here because in the given position we don't know if we are inside the special block or not (delimiters are not oriented).

So what I really do to solve this is first I parse the whole text for delimiters of special blocks then I get the indexes of "bad" lines and then I apply my regex substitutions line by line checking if this line is not one of the "bad" lines. But if my regex must apply to more than one line it becomes more complicated. And I'm sure there are some pretty smart and easy ways to handle this.

So basically what I need is to be able to exclude some fragments of the text (by theirs spans) from the `re.sub` when it applies to the whole text. Even if the regex only intersects with the span (not necessarily contains it). So that I can apply the first regex, take the spans of specials blocks by their begin and end indexes and exclude these spans from the second regex. How is this possible?

Right now I have this solution (the example above is simplified, sorry):

```
def find_code_lines(data):
    # Search for blocks by regex They can be empty!
    r = re.compile(r'(\n----(?=\n)(?P<group1>[\s\S]*?\n)----\n)')
    
    # Delete all '\n' which are not line breaks (there are some of them in formulas etc.)
    data_edited = data.replace('\\n', '')

    # Save spans by symbol indexes
    char_spans = []
    for m in r.finditer(data_edited):
        #print(m.span(1))
        #print(m.span[1])
        char_spans.append(m.span(1))
    
    # Calculate spans by line indexes
    line_spans = []
    for span in char_spans:
        begin = data_edited[:span[0]].count("\n") + 2
        end = data_edited[:span[1]].count("\n") - 1
        line_spans.append((begin, end))
        
    return line_spans

# Check if index is inside one of spans
def in_spans(spans, line_index):
    res = False
    for span in spans:
        if line_index >= span[0] and line_index < span[1]:
            res = True
    return res

# Parse text by blocks
code_lines = find_code_lines(data)

lines_edited = []
data_lines = data.splitlines()
replace_count = 0
for i in range(len(data_lines)):
    if in_spans(code_lines, i):
        lines_edited.append(data_lines[i])
        #print('line in spans:', i)
    else:
        data_tuple = re.subn(r'(?P<group1>\s|^|\s\()\$(?P<group2>[^\$`\r\n]{1,1000}?)\$',
                            r'\1stem:[\2]', 
                            data_lines[i])
        if data_tuple[1] == 0:
            lines_edited.append(data_lines[i])
        else:
            lines_edited.append(data_tuple[0])
            replace_count += data_tuple[1]
lines_edited.append('')
data = '\n'.join(lines_edited)
log_it('Replaced Math blocks', replace_count)
```

UPD
I added more text to the input example because some of the solutions below can handle only specific versions of inputs (which are easier). So the most difficult one so far is like this:

```
some text
----
text inside special block
----
some text
----
----
some text
----
text inside special block
----
some text
```

Expected output:

```
some TEXT
----
text inside special block
----
some TEXT
----
----
some TEXT
----
text inside special block
----
some TEXT
```

Comment: *"But if my regex must apply to more than one line it becomes more complicated."*: why would it?

Comment: Because I need to exclude fragments not by line but by their spans. So I cannot iterate over lines anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` + substitution function ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bxg1WW/2)):

```py
import re

text = """\
some text
----
text inside special block
----
some text
----
----
some text
----
text inside special block
----
some text"""


pat = r"(.*?)(-+\n.*?-+(?:\n|\Z))(.*?)(?=-+|\Z)"


def repl_fn(g):
    return (
        g.group(1).replace("text", "TEXT")
        + g.group(2)
        + g.group(3).replace("text", "TEXT")
    )


text = re.sub(pat, repl_fn, text, flags=re.S)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
some TEXT
----
text inside special block
----
some TEXT
----
----
some TEXT
----
text inside special block
----
some TEXT
```

Comment: I didn't mention it but of course special blocks can be spread in text in any order and quantity and even worse - there can be empty blocks. So I don't think your solution can handle any combination right?

Comment: @AlexeyBogdanov Please update your question with some more complicated example + expected output

Comment: Oh yes that works Thanks! It basically uses the same idea as in previous answer - we apply one regex to the whole text and then make replacements only in specific match groups. I will definitely use something like this thank you!

Comment: I'm playing with your solution further and I realized that it can handle only cases in which we have special block in the end of input text. If it ends with regular text this last fragment will not be captured by your regex.
And we can siplify your regex cutting the third option - `(.*?)(-+\n.*?-+(?:\n|\Z))` and get the same result. If we delete this line of course: `+ g.group(3).replace("text", "TEXT")`

Comment: I updated the description with more difficult input example such that your regex doesn't cover it all. I wish it can cover it because your solution looks very short and easy. But so far I don't know if it can handle this updated example or not.

Comment: Yes now it's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is creating an array of positions using the separator regexp, and then doing different replacements between those positions, like this:

```
import re


def replace(data, separator_re, replace_outside_special_func):
  poss = [0]
  for match in re.finditer(separator_re, data):
    poss.extend((match.start(), match.end()))
  poss.append(len(data))
  return ''.join(
      data[poss[i] : poss[i + 1]] if i & 3
      else replace_outside_special_func(data[poss[i] : poss[i + 1]])
      for i in range(0, len(poss) - 1))


data = '''some text
----
text inside special block
----
some text
'''
print(replace(
    data, r'(?m)^----$',
    lambda data: data.replace('text', 'TEXT')))
```

It prints:

```
some TEXT
----
text inside special block
----
some TEXT
```

Some explanation:

- We use `re.finditer` and `match.start()` and `match.end()` to find the start and end positions (within-string indexes) of each separator. We save these positions to the array `poss` in increasing order.
- We also add `0` to the beginning of `poss` and `len(data)` to the end of poss, to make sure we won't miss any block near the start and end of the input.
- We iterate over each substring marked by adjacent positions in `poss`, e.g. `data[poss[0] : poss[1]]`, `data[poss[1] : poss[2]]`, `data[poss[2] : poss[3]]` etc.
- `data[poss[i] : poss[i + 1]]` is:

  - If `i % 4 == 0`: Normal block, e.g. `'some text\n'`.
  - If `i % 4 == 1`: Seperator after normal block, e.g. `'----'`.
  - If `i % 4 == 2`: Special block, e.g. `'\ntext inside special block\n'`.
  - If `i % 4 == 3`: Seperator after special block, e.g. `'----'`.
- We apply the replacement only in normal blocks.

---

Here is a shorter solution:

```
import re

data = '''some text
----
text inside special block
----
some text
'''
print(re.sub(
    r'(?s)(.*?)(\Z|\n(?:\Z|----(?:\Z|\n.*?(?:\Z|\n(?:\Z|----(?:\Z|\n))))))',
    lambda match: match.group(1).replace('text', 'TEXT') + match.group(2),
    data))
```

I think this shorter solution is slower. You may want to run some benchmarks on long input.

Some explanation:

- `(?s)` sets the `s` flag so that `.` will match any character, including `\n`.
- `(.*?)` matches the normal block, and saves it to `match.group(1)`.
- `(\Z|\n(?:\Z|----(?:\Z|\n.*?(?:\Z|\n(?:\Z|----(?:\Z|\n))))))` matches the separator + special block + separator, and saves it to `match.group(2)`.
- The `.*?` is like `.*`, but shorter matches are tried first. Without the `?`, that part of the regexp would match the entire input.
- The `TEXT` replacement is only applied to normal blocks (`match.group(1)`).
- The regexp contains many instances of `\Z|\n...` so that it matches correctly even if the input string ends early (e.g. within a special block).

---

When doing string processing with regexps, these are useful ideas:

1. Match everything with a single regexp of the form `(...)|(...)|...`, and sort it out in the replacement function with `if match.group(1) is not None:` etc.
2. Match with multiple short regexps (e.g. `^----$` and `text`), and write code which joins the matches and replacements together.
3. Match with a single long regexp, do partial matches at end-of-string with `\Z|...`.

The longer solution above did #2, and the shorter one did #3. For tokenization (such as removing comments from C source code), #1 is useful.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Looks comlicated but it should work. I wonder if it can be done easier. I'm sure that is very often situation in text converters when substitutions should be made only in some areas of document. And the areas are stored by their spans in original document.

Comment: A simpler and correct solution would be great, and I'm also very interested in learning it. Let's see...

Comment: I've added a shorter solution to my answer.

Comment: Yes the shorter one looks easier Thanks!